# JSON decoding error in Go: "invalid character '\\' looking for beginning of object key string"

Tags: json, go

I'm using the `vpp` package of [MicroMDM](https://micromdm.io/) but noticed that initializing a VPP client, which was working before, has stopped working. The error I get occurs in the client's `GetClientContext()` method (https://github.com/micromdm/micromdm/blob/ea5c0a3865e87f5de04a58dc2c67b5fa6f6fd7de/vpp/clientconfigsrv.go#L99-L117), which I've modified with a `fmt.Println()` call to print the `context`:

```
// GetClientContext gets the values that determine which mdm server is associated with a VPP account token
func (c *Client) GetClientContext() (*ClientContext, error) {
    // Get the ClientConfigSrv info
    clientConfigSrv, err := c.GetClientConfigSrv()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "get ClientContext request")
    }

    // Get the ClientContext string
    var context = clientConfigSrv.ClientContext
    fmt.Println(context)

    // Convert the string to a ClientContext type
    var clientContext ClientContext
    err = json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(context)).Decode(&clientContext)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "decode ClientContext")
    }

    return &clientContext, nil
}
```

where `ClientContext` is the following struct (https://github.com/micromdm/micromdm/blob/ea5c0a3865e87f5de04a58dc2c67b5fa6f6fd7de/vpp/clientconfigsrv.go#L10-L14):

```
// Contains information that associates your particular mdm server to a VPP account token
type ClientContext struct {
    HostName string `json:"hostname"`
    GUID     string `json:"guid"`
}
```

when I run a script that invokes `vpp.NewClient()` (which, in turn, invokes this method), I see the following output:

```
> go run main.go getVPPAssets
INFO[0000] Using config file: .vpp-client.env           
{\"hostname\":\"https://your.server.com\",\"guid\":\"7c66e635-ef07-4e26-86a3-c953e4e8f16d\"}
FATA[0000] Failed to initialize VPP client: GetClientContext request: decode ClientContext: invalid character '\\' looking for beginning of object key string 
exit status 1
```

Note that the line with

```
{\"hostname\":\"https://your.server.com\",\"guid\":\"7c66e635-ef07-4e26-86a3-c953e4e8f16d\"}
```

is produced by the `fmt.Println()` statement I added. I've tried to reproduce this error with the following minimal example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

type ClientContext struct {
    HostName string `json:"hostname"`
    GUID     string `json:"guid"`
}

func main() {
    context := "{\"hostname\":\"https://your.server.com\",\"guid\":\"7c66e635-ef07-4e26-86a3-c953e4e8f16d\"}"

    var clientContext ClientContext
    if err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(context)).Decode(&clientContext); err != nil {
        logrus.Fatalf("decode ClientContext: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", clientContext)
}
```

However, this example decodes the `clientConfigSrv.ClientContext` string into a `ClientContext` correctly.

I believe there is something about the escaping of quotes that has changed in the response returned by Apple's VPP service and is causing this decoder to choke; any ideas how to fix this error?

Comment: Note that your attempt at reproducing the issue is wrong, fmt.Println will not print single backslash in front of a double quote if that's what is in the string. The actual string contained in `clientConfigSrv.ClientContext` looks like this `"{\\\"hostname\\\":\\\"https://your.server.com\\\",\\\"guid\\\":\\\"7c66e635-ef07-4e26-86a3-c953e4e8f16d\\\"}"`. See [here](https://play.golang.com/p/_UCJMfWLI-D) and [here](https://play.golang.com/p/fC6zQRE-MLT). You should probably open an issue on their github, if it hasn't been already.

Comment: Debugging tip, use `%q` to print the _exact_ string so you can see all characters.

Comment: I suspect this is a symptom of having json _inside_ json as an escaped string. If you need to do that, you almost always want to encode it with base64 (or another encoding), or, better yet, have a single object, but defer further decoding with json.RawMessage and the Unmarshaler interface.